# Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

Recently on one of my machines, my client (WCF client) is having problem talking to WCF server. Both server and client are running on the same machine. The machine is Windows7 64 bit machine. It used to work fine until recently. The same software is working fine on all other machines with exactly same configuration. I am really confused here. Could someone please let me know what could be the problem?

Exception Type: 
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Message: 
Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.   This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is not using security.

Stack Trace: 
System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessageCore(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ServerSecurityChannel`1.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationState)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.SecurityReplyChannel.ProcessReceivedRequest(RequestContext requestContext, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveRequestAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult.ProcessInnerItem(RequestContext innerItem, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.OnInnerReceiveDone()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.InnerTryReceiveCompletedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.Utility.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, ItemDequeuedCallback dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueueChannel`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(TDisposable item, ItemDequeuedCallback dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.Enqueue(QueueItemType item, ItemDequeuedCallback dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, ItemDequeuedCallback callback)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnGetContextCore(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnGetContext(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.Utility.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.WaitCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)

Thank you,
Suresh